# Permanently convert tabs to spaces in vi / vim

Tags: vim

If I wanted to have traditional indentation in vi / vim, I would enter these commands:

```
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
:set expandtab
```

It is tedious to type those commands every time I open a file. How do I permanently store those settings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a file in your home directory called **`.vimrc`**, and put your commands in there:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Ubuntu's [Vim Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto) has a few pointers to basic customisation, if you want to dig deeper there's the [Vim Book](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/) and the [FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html) as well.

vi-improved.org also has [a nice, big example](http://www.vi-improved.org/vimrc.php) of one person's .vimrc for you to rummage around in.

Answer (score 4):

Store

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

or

```
set ts=4 sw=4 
set expandtab
```

In your `~/.vimrc` file. E.G. `/home/user/.vimrc` or `/home/$(whoami)/.vimrc`. You can use your other settings in .vimrc as well, the ones you regularly use, for example `syntax on` if you use the full version of VIM.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open the terminal in `\home\user\exampleuser\`, (the default directory), create the file `.vimrc`. If you really like vim, you can type `vim .vimrc` into the command line, or you can use nano. This file will control vim. Then type your code you want to set here like this:

`set expandtab`

(notice no colons (:))
Then, save the file and you're done!

Comment: A `:` before a command in vimrc is harmless. `:set` is the same as `set` in vimrc. See [`:h script`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#vim-script-intro).